# New Ubuntu versions on older Compaq Presario

Tags: windows-vista, compaq, presario

Does latest versions of Ubuntu work on older computers like a Compaq Presario that was preinstalled with Windows Vista

Comment: For reference: from my own experience. If the machine has no obscure hardware... if it runs XP it will run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's performance will depend on your computers specs check this link for ubuntu's minimum requirements http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ if your PC doesn't meet those requirements you clould look at alternatives such as Xubuntu KUbuntu and Lubuntu.
I also suggest you download an LTS release and not the latest release

Comment: I have actually run Unity/14.04 on a Core 2 duo with 2GB RAM - it was SLOW but usable. Don't expect to be able to e.g. view web pages with many images or do other tasks that requires high amounts of RAM though.

Comment: I had a Compaq 610 intel Celeron single core 1GB RAM and Ubuntu 12.04 worked perfectly. If that helps